# dynamic array pointer to binary file

Tags: c++, memory, binary, storage

Know this might be rather basic, but I been trying to figure out how to one after create a dynamic array such as

```
double* data = new double[size];
```

be used as a source of data to be kept in to a binary file such as

```
ofstream fs("data.bin",ios:binary");
fs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *> (data),size*sizeof(double));
```

When I finish writing, I attempt to read the file through

```
double* data = new double[size];
ifstream fs("data.bin",ios:binary");
fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (data),size*sizeof(double));
```

However I seem to encounter a run time error when reading the data. Do you guys have any advice how i should attempt to write a dynamic array using pointers passed from other methods to be stored in binary files?

Comment: Have you checked if the file is open using `is_open()` before reading?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. I did check if the file is open first. But it doesn't seem to work, i'm not sure which part i did wrong though, the read or the write part.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps you could reduce it to a simple test case and post it here. Here is what I tried: http://codepad.org/7cOi0xpA

Comment: Have some trouble loading the link, but thanks Firas Assaad. I assume the problem could be the way i pass in the array to the method I save the data. 
The source of the double array is a private data of an object. I use another object to get the array using this method double* getData(); which will return the pointer.
I then pass the pointer receive to the saving method. The pointer is pass from the origin obj -> handler obj-> save ();
Could this be one of key that cause the problem?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<double>`, there's no reason to have manual memory management.

Comment: It will be great to be able to use vector, however I am using some library which requires double array. So i most probably have to figure some way with array

Comment: std::vector can usually be used in place of plain arrays.  If you need to pass an array to the library, that's fine: vector<double> vec; cFunctionTakingArray(&vec[0], vec.size()); // is a common pattern for C++ code calling C functions taking arrays with sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hy:)

> ```
> If you use Unix you have some functions:    int read(int fd, void
> ```
>
> *buf, int count);.   int write (int fd, void *buf, int nbytes);.

```
The functions are verry fast because
are kernel-functions.

i run your code and everything was
ok : 

      1 #include <iostream>
      2 #include <fstream>
      3 #include <cstring>
      4 using namespace std;
      5 
      6 int main()
      7 {
      8     double * s;
      9     int ns = 10;                    //information
     10     s = new double[ns];
     11 
     12     for (int i = 0 ; i < ns ; ++i)
     13         s[i] = 17*i + 23;           // i put my information here
     14 
     15     ofstream os("data.txt", ios::binary);
     16     os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (s), sizeof(double) * ns);
     17     os.close();
     18 
     19     double * final;
     20     final = new double[ns];
     21 
     22     ifstream is("data.txt", ios::binary);
     23     is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(final), sizeof(double) * ns);
     24     is.close();
     25 
     26     for (int i=0; i < ns; ++i)
     27         cout<<s[i]<<" "<<final[i]<<"\n";
     28 
     29     return 0;
     30 }

~
```

> ```
> none@Brusture:~/Desktop$ g++ -o test
> test.cpp  none@Brusture:~/Desktop$
> ./test  23 23 40 40 57 57 74 74 91
> 91 108 108 125 125 142 142 159 159
> 176 176
> ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort and time to test out my problem. It really did seem to run well now, the problem was some where else that lead to the error to the persistent method.Thanks again serbanlupu.

Answer (score 3):

Streams  are not the only nor always the best way to access binary files. This is another way that uses the virtual memory mechanisms of the operating system (i.e. the same thing that make your memory swap to disk):

```
  template<class T>
    struct BinaryData{
    BinaryData(std::string const& fname,unsigned size):_size(size) {
       int fd=open(fname.c_str(),O_RDWR,O_CREAT);
       //if modifying to different size or creating
       ftruncate(fd,size*sizeof(T));
       //get the memory
       _data=reinterpret_cast<T*>(mmap(0,size*sizeof(T),PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,fd,0));
       fclose(fd);
    }

    ~BinaryData(){
      munmap(_data);
    }
    T* begin(){return _data; }
    T* end(){return _data+_size; }
    private:
     T* _data;
     unsigned _size;
    };
```

This just makes the memory swap to a differnt swap file, i.e. the one you specify. The flags chosen will always force it to write the contents to disk, either when the program exits or munmap is invoked. This example of course does not have anything in terms of error checking and the syntax only works on POSIX systems. However Windows has identical semantics in its CreateFileMapping function.

Comment: thanks for the response, i never heard of such method before. Truly eye opening, I shall look into it. Thanks!